# Filling tables with data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have created Relational Model in Oracle SQL Data Modeler with all tables and relations. I would like to generate a DDL to use it in Oracle SQL Developer and work with some SQL queries.

Before generating DDL I would like to fill all the tables with data, so I can put DDL with all data for tables prepared in it.

So, how can fill tables with data in Oracle SQL Data Modeler?

Comment: I never worked with oracle sql data modeler, but you can execute `insert` statements in oracle sqldeveloper.. why not do it there?

Comment: I'm just starting my adventure with SQL and I'm afraid of putting large amount of data via insert command.

Comment: how much is large? you could import data from a file.. there's multiple ways of doing that. can you give an example of what you're trying to insert?

Comment: "I'm afraid of putting large amount of data via insert command" -- and how, do you think, other tools do it? Create a `for-loop` and use random numbers, guids, etc. BTW - google for tools that do it for you

Comment: Okay, after running DDL script I have figured out that Oracle SQL Developer has option which I was looking for. Thank you all for help.

Comment: See:http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7405/generate-sample-data-for-an-oracle-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables can be filled with data in SQL Oracle Developer, filling it before in Data modeler is not needed.